# How to implement more than one switch button?

Tags: html, css

I have created a switch toggle, if i create more than one switch it is not working Exactly.

**Html**

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" 
           checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" 
           checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Here Js Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dgj7s5sk/
Some one help me out in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have more than one element with the same id.

Change the id of the second `input` to something else (along with the `for` value in your `label`) so that the `label`s know which element they are related to.

This works:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked="checked" />
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" checked="checked" />
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

- See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xavlec/u8qy44hk/)

Answer (score 0):

Each "switch toggle" must have must have its own ID.
Try:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch1" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch1">
...
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch2" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch2" checked>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IDs instead of classes. Except the wraping `div`, assign IDs to each of the elements.